# java.lang.LinkageError: JAXB version mismatch issue with CXF 2.3 and JBoss 4.2.3

Tags: jboss, jaxb, cxf

I am developing a REST web service with Apache CXF 2.3 and deploying in JBoss 4.2.3 GA. When I try to access my web service, I am getting this following error
java.lang.LinkageError: JAXB 2.0 API is being loaded from the bootstrap classloader, but this RI needs 2.1 API. Use the endorsed directory mechanism to place jaxb-api.jar in the bootstrap classloader.

I was able to fix this error by adding the correct version of JAXB api jar in \lib\endorsed folder. But I am doubtful whether it will interfere in any other web application JAXB related functionality. One more web application is using some other version of JAXB. Is there any other graceful way of solving this issue. Thanks for any advice.